# Ignition Gazebo: Cannot Use Diffdrive from URDF

Tags: gazebo-ignition, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I tried to build the diffdrive robot by reference to [ros_ign_gazebo_demos](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/dashing/ros_ign_gazebo_demos). But I can not move it.

Below is the launch file.

[test_description_publisher.launch.py](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16166558533417351.py)

Below is robot URDF.

[test.urdf.xacro.model](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16166555122733548.model)

I realize that "ign sdf -p test.urdf > test.sdf" change the URDF to the SDF without  tag.
Below is robot SDF.

[test.sdf.model](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16166561432661883.model)

I think that is why my robot dont move.
How can I get correct SDF?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26724/ignition-gazebo:-cannot-use-diffdrive-from-urdf/) by [M-Hijikata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45078/m-hijikata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I misunderstood that  tag can not be used in the ignition gazebo.

In the URDF, the diffdrive plugin is written like below.

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin
    filename="libignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system.so"
    name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">
    <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
    <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
    <wheel_separation>1.2</wheel_separation>
    <wheel_radius>0.4</wheel_radius>
    <odom_publish_frequency>1</odom_publish_frequency>
    <topic>cmd_vel</topic>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

I can move my robot with the ignition's topic like below.

```
ign topic -t "/cmd_vel" -m ignition.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 0.5}, angular: {z: 0.05}"
```

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [M-Hijikata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/45078/m-hijikata/) with karma: 16 on 2021-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0